# C++ push_back 2d deque

Tags: c++, data-structures, deque

I want to expend the first dimension of my 2d deque in C++ but the arguments are not right.

```
struct storingDataStruct{
    int posX;
    int posY;
};

deque<deque<storingDataStruct>> dataStorage;
dataStorage.push_back(new deque<storingDataStruct>); //doesnt work
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
dataStorage.push_back(deque<storingDataStruct>());
```

You're constructing a `deque<storingDataStruct>`, so all you need is to construct an instance of it in place.

If you used `typedef`, it may become more obvious:

```
typedef std::deque<storingDataStruct> StoringDeque;
deque<StoringDeque> dataStorage;
//...    
dataStorage.push_back(StoringDeque());
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!